# Best practice for importing maven projects into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

Pretty new to all this, so wanted to do what is the best practice for this scenario:

I checkout a project from GitHub that has POM file so it is a maven project.
Now I want to write code in it in Eclipse.
Ok so do I first run something like

```
mvn clean package 
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

And then from Eclipse I say File->Import->Maven project ?

Or do I open a project in Eclipse and use Maven2Eclipse project inside eclipse to build it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the two maven commands.

If you have the correct plugins you can just do File->Import->Maven project->'select the project'

M2Eclipse will recognise it and make all the changes needed.

Comment: "M2Eclipse will recognise it and make all the changes needed" ... cool, is it some new feature? Last time I used it was like four months ago and coworkers were telling me about doing elise:eclipse command.

Comment: Never had to do that in the last 4 years.  We actually checkout pure maven project from svn and it works out of the box.  (Those project do NOT contain any .project or .classpath files)  Some goes for basic importing

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` will only generate basic project and classpath files.  If you want to enable WTP or other components, m2eclipse is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the EGit plugin in eclipse. Clone the repo in the Git Repositories view, and then there is an "import maven project" option in there. That way, the project is recognized by eclipse as both being in a git repo, and a maven project.

mvn eclipse:eclipse generates an eclipse .project for you, so yes, you could simply import that as a maven project. Even if you do not open it as a maven project, the m2e plugin will "convert it".

Either way, you would use m2e to build.